# Java Socket freezing issue

Tags: java, sockets

I made an example of what I want my program to be. The problem is that I can't make my socket connection to work properly (the way I want it to work). And I don't know where the problem is here.

```
public class TestChat extends Frame {

public static Panel1 p1;
public static Panel2 p2;
public static TestChat tc;

public TestChat() {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    p1 = new Panel1();
    p2 = new Panel2();
    add(p1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    tc = new TestChat();
    tc.pack();
    tc.setVisible(true);
    ///*
    try {
        TestChat.p2.run();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO here");
    }
    //*/
}

public void change(int to) {
    if (to == 1) {
        tc.remove(p2);
        tc.add(p1);
    }
    if (to == 2) {
        tc.remove(p1);
        tc.add(p2);
    }
    tc.pack();
}
}

public class Panel1 extends Panel implements ActionListener{

public Button button = new Button("Launch chat");

public Panel1() {
    super();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Label label = new Label("Launcher panel here");
    add(label);
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        TestChat.tc.change(2);
        /*
        try {
            TestChat.p2.run();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO here");
        }
        //*/
    }
}

}

public class Panel2 extends Panel implements ActionListener {

private static final int LOGIN_MAX = 300;
public static TextArea ta = new TextArea();
public static TextField tf = new TextField();
public static TextArea logins = new TextArea();
public static PrintWriter out = null;
public static String[] loginList = new String[LOGIN_MAX];
public static int loginCount = 0;
public Panel temp = new Panel();
public Button startButton = new Button("Start!");
///*
public String fromServer;
public BufferedReader in = null;
public BufferedReader stdIn;
public Socket kkSocket = null;
//*/

public Panel2() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    temp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ta.setEditable(false);
    tf.addActionListener(this);
    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    logins.setEditable(false);
    temp.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    temp.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(temp);
    add(logins, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

//private static void makeLogins() {
public static void makeLogins() {
    String userArea = loginList[0] + "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < loginCount; i++) {
        userArea = userArea + loginList[i] + "\n";
    }
    logins.setText(userArea);
}

public void run() throws IOException {

    kkSocket = null;

    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        //System.err.println("Can't host to server.");
        System.out.println("Can't host to server.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to server.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer;

    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
        validate();
        if (fromServer.startsWith("cmd_newUser_")) {
            loginList[loginCount++] = fromServer.substring(12);
            if (loginCount > 1) {
                Arrays.sort(loginList, 1, loginCount - 1);
            }
            makeLogins();
        } else if (fromServer.startsWith("cmd_deleteUser_")) {
            String tmp = fromServer.substring(15);
            for (int i = 0; i < loginCount; i++) {
                if (loginList[i].equals(tmp)) {
                    loginList[i] = "" + ((char) 255);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Arrays.sort(loginList, 1, loginCount);
            loginCount--;
            makeLogins();
        } else {
            ta.append(fromServer + "\n");
        }
        if (fromServer.equals("Bye.")) {
            break;
        }
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
}

private void sendStr(PrintWriter out) {
    if (tf.getText() != "") {
        out.println(tf.getText());
        tf.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == tf) {
        sendStr(out);
    } else if (e.getSource() == startButton) {
        System.out.println("I make some actions in the original proj");
    }
}
}
```

When I use it this way, then my program connects and everything works fine. But I want to start connection from Panel1 class when the button is pressed (commented call). When I try to call it from Panel1, then my whole program freezes. Where is the problem here and how can I solve it?

P.S. Here is my server code (just in case)

```
public class KKMultiServer extends Frame {

public static int userCount = 0;
public static Label users;
public static KKMultiServerThread[] userList=new KKMultiServerThread[100];
public static int writer=0;
public static int curNum=1;

public KKMultiServer() {
    super("Server");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    users = new Label("Users online: " + userCount);
    add(users);
    setLocation(200, 200);
    setResizable(false);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean listening = true;
    KKMultiServer server = new KKMultiServer();
    server.pack();
    server.setVisible(true);

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (listening) {                             
        userList[writer]=new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
        System.out.println("Client added!");
        userCount++;
        users.setText("Users online: " + userCount);
        userList[writer++].start();         


    }

    serverSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Just to start with, `static` is not your friend.  Be very careful declaring `static` variables, they will come back to bite you if you are not careful...just saying

Comment: There's too much code for me to sort through right now, but my suspicion is that you're trying to run your socket code on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `static` references in this way is a very bad design.  You run the risk of not knowing exactly what you referencing.
2. Swing is single threaded environment,  That is, all interactions and modifications to the UI are expected to be executed from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Any operations which block this thread, like, say, blocking I/O or long running loops, will prevent the UI from processing new events and paint requests.

You have basically fluked it up to now.  When `main` is run by the JVM it is running in, what is commonly known as, the "main" thread.  When you start using any of the Swing components, the Swing API will start the "Event Dispatching Thread"...

So what's happening, you are launching your UI portion of you application, it's context is being moved over to the EDT, while the `run` method `p2` is continuing to run in the `main` thread.

Now that you want to start the comms from the button, you've moved the execution context to the EDT, which is making it look like you application has hung....

Now, you have two problems.  The first is, you need to get your comms off the EDT, your second is, you should never modify or update the UI from any thread other than the EDT...

There are a number of solutions that are available to you, `SwingWorker` is probably going to be the simplest for your problem.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details